# Foreach loop causes NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, string, foreach, nullreferenceexception, arrays

At the top of my code (before constructor) I write:
`String[] CAN = null;`

This string array is updated in another function.

Later in my code I have this foreach loop:

```
foreach (String str in CAN)
{
    if(str.Contains("18FA07FE"))
        cmdResult = true;
    else
        cmdResult = false;
}
```

I have tried to debug, and at the line of the foreach statement I can see that the CAN string array has successfully been updated, and now contains 1211 elements.

So I don't really know why it's giving me this exception.

Comment: Well, do you know where exactly the exception is occurring?

Comment: Did you check the contents of your string array?..maybe one of the elements of the array is null. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the problem is only related to the code you've shown, and the code you've described, and it's true that the array has elements, then the only possible explanation is that one of the elements in `CAN` is a null element, and thus it isn't the foreach *itself* that throws the exception, but this line:

```
if (str.Contains(...))
    ^^^
     |
     +-- null
```

Comment: I agree on that.. .just like i said in my first comment, check the string array. :)

Comment: Yeah thanks, it turned out that the very last element of the string array was null. Fixed now, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe one of the string value is a null

```
string [] CAN =  { "first", "second", null, "fourth" };

            foreach ( string str in CAN ) {
                if ( str.Contains( "fourth" ) ) {
                    Console.WriteLine( "Success" );
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get the NullPointer? Is it the loop or the if? I guess your array contains a 'null' element which throws this NPE.